# Classical and quantum angular momenta

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, rotational-kinematics

Say a macroscopic object of known mass and elemental composition is rotating, and its angular momentum $L$ is determined. Let $L$ be divided by the number of constituent subatomic particles $N$ (this can be approximated from the mass and composition). Now, this quantity $L/N$ would still have units of angular momentum, and thus mathematically is some multiple $n$ of Planck's constant $h$:

$$
\frac{L}{N} = nh.
$$

My question is, could such a quantity have any physical meaning? How close would *n* be to reasonable rotational quantum number values?

(I am aware some people will be tempted to consider this muddling of classical and quantum properties heresy. But where would science be without curiosity?)

Comment: Are you sure you can divide angular momentum as easily as you have done above? Is it not a vector sum, rather than a scalar quantity. Nothing wrong with curiosity, but I just wonder what we would learn from doing this that we don't know already?

Comment: I think coherent states are situations where you might find usefulness in quantities similar to $L/N$. For example vortices in superfluids. But I'm not sure about this direct division of the angular momentum operator as you have done.

Comment: I assume you've done the back of the envelope calculation? For an $L\sim 0.1 Js$ gyroscope with $N \sim 10^{25}$ you get an $n\sim 10^8$. But what are you going to do with that number? Reassure yourself that your system is classical?